# Echarts how to make chart span 2 (or more) grid cells

Tags: echarts

In Apache echarts I want to make more advanced layouts akin to `matplotlib` `gridspec` or row and col spanning in `plotly`. Is this doable? For example is it possible to make [this layout](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_multicolumn.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-gridspec-multicolumn-py) in echarts?

Comment: https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#ECharts%20Basic%20Concepts%20Overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify each [grid](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid) in absolute or relative coordiantes.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-anscombe-quartet&edit=1&reset=1&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggggGzTAvDA2gKBj0KLwEYAGAOgoBoYAOGgFgF1aSjcm6YA2KgE4ArO07kAzDXoB2KsIZjSeQdMZUGZJaVxkyaphInauZZmtWC-JvAN5yATGw7Lc53uYfWXOsg7WUGs7iuHIeGg42uMJqMXyKJNoEroG8qmZRPPRMGT6mUrxMMsGuqoVUMjJRehZUXtXu2VRaebZqAmTGrW5qUi0hfrWdUWGydd4hMeHFrIk-yb7U9lTME65Z_BVV3Z0B_jPdZWN61frLmg0GQVF29HaK3Y0wMRKC1f7lZKLdo5vMkd0pvQYjJjHMSAsuBsBApMrEKmsdBs5DJ-usrgwSkirsxtiFkSw4bwYg5vgMjjBBmT0cT5IioWo5II0djeAIGG9EvhWABufCgSCwAC2CAATgBrAAyAEswABTADyAAdYDgAN4kBBgaUiqDS8AALhgADMEGgIHKfGgEAAjOVoI0a5TGkCi3VQOWio0AcgAntgYNRhDAAFQwAAeMAA1DAJN7WmbpQBzMA-0XJgAWUG9JAAvlbZXKAMpQX1oOWO8SlpUVmDeiAgNDSuA5oj5khQECNvVKyvO13uz0-_04IOhiPR2OtmDtoiIZBGyHEZREJ0roigV1wRe8LriZQQX1Cm2Nn1gcBy6fKWcrtfrzei7d4By8YatA9Hk8Ouvn-VX0i5uIsxELMuZ8iAKr6mAAZrnqUDln2pAeuGUBGgARCgkCgMel4QDAACOACuYoelAaGtOWxqoXWwBymAHqivGVYQUaFB5j4Sbpk-S5qjAlHUd6MgAKTxjAna9nWwmiemSZZj6Un0BmcqZgJpIiTOrS8fx8kifQ4k-hICkwAA7s2UAZj6wjCLpMBKSpPpqd6GniFpcpUTpoknlAnZCh59CmXA5kOdZol2bJqkhc5yi8TJcmSTZXk-X5JlmRZdYOEZYVxd6wh8OpgEgT4nbdtKEl3iaA5IAxPoAOKiiAhFKjAaoILmRoABRqsAuYAJTTje4YoOG0oQIuLkwJxzYAJJgHAcrhqx9BCrKi0wCKC0wC-UWkLxk1wDNc0bWQS0rYGS0IBtW03quE1cQd81Gg4J2pmda0XY9FDbTde33RtEjPat60fTO4JEL6Q0jWN0W3dNs0Pa9y0vbwQOUsG13NTD-1w0dAMI-9qNfRjP3Y49uPI_jXyE7td0k7GZPnUdaOgzAFrpnKo3Ljt-4wGACBCrW3pTUx67VgLEDAFVnrCyug3DRAv2Ldz4NywrZ3c_OCBGhr6BoLgFA2EQIoSjK8pGkbUqFsqUDiOj5VELz_M-lNQvvmJvo1j64uS4xruyyNqvHUrEPy7TgfrhrWtIKgGC6Abb3G4WZtihb8pWzbmncw7AvOy73Oi57EveVLvvB6rT1ByrtPl-HUeR8gOu4AC3PmybtYt5bKrpy5md89nABq0vKPndZe0XPvc37IeHUa_0V_7tOzzXC7wFHDd7uu7em_HKeKp315cmBQA):

```js
grid: [
    { left: '7%', top: '7%', right: '7%', height: '25%' },
    { left: '7%', top: '37%', width: '55%', height: '25%' },
    { left: '7%', bottom: '7%', width: '25%', height: '25%' },
    { right: '7%', bottom: '7%', width: '27%', height: '56%' }
```

Comment: Sweet I tried playing with these numbers but couldn't get anything useful. Thanks a lot.